# Pig Connection to localhost:8020 failed. Unable to setup job history server

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn

I have installed a single node hadoop cluster on my local machine. I'm using it for 1-2 months now and I have execute few MR codes without any problem.
But recently while studying Pig, I found out that I was unable to start the job history server.
To solve this problem, I added below lines in the mapred-site.xml

But after making the above changes, I'm getting the below error while executing basic HDFS commands.

Even a basic hadoop fs ls throws the above error.

I have removed the above configuration from mapred-site.xml, tried formatting namenode but still the same issue. Can someone please help me as I'm stuck with this for very long

mapred-site.xml

```
<property> 
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name> 
    <value>localhost:10020</value> <!-- hostname of machine where jobhistory 
service is started --> 
</property> 
<property> 
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name> 
    <value>localhost:19888</value> 
</property>
```

error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in 
[jar:file:/usr/share/java/slf4j/slf4j- 
log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] SLF4J: Found binding 
in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/slf4j/slf4j- 
jdk14.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] SLF4J: See 
http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation. 
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] 
18/12/23 22:22:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop 
library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 
ls: Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to localhost:8020 failed on connection 
exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details 
see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Comment: Slf4j is not the issue. `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details 
see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

Comment: If you read the link in the error, it'll say not to use localhost in the property files

Comment: Thanks for the response @cricket_007. I do not have localhost in any property file. I removed the above changes from mapred-site.xml but still facing the same issue. Also, if slf4j is not the issue then why do I see the 'SLF4J: Class path contains....' message coz I never saw this message before.

Comment: Multiple Hadoop packages contain Slf4j. There's not really much to do about it... And if you removed localhost, then that's still the defaults, so you will want to read the link in the error and go though each of the listed steps to validate a proper connection. More importantly, it's not clear how/if you're even starting the history server

Comment: @cricket_007 I am now able to start history server with ./mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver. But I'm facing the connection refused problem. I can't understand what the issue is as everything was working fine before. I'll read the link in error for further analysis.